# Adding terms in long format in R with missing data

Tags: r

I am trying to add the number of times col1 occurs under the name variable disregarding the missing value. It should be 2 times, but when I use the length and count functions they always return 3.

```
M = data.frame( Name = c('name','name1','name','name1','name','name1'), Col1 = c(NA,1,3,4,5,NA) , Col2 = c(1,1,NA,5,8,4))

myData <- aggregate(M[,2],
                    by = list(VAR = M$Name), 
                    FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x,na.rm=T), sd = sd(x,na.rm=T),n=length(x)))
myData <- do.call(data.frame, myData)

myData
#> x.n
#   3
#I want it to say 2 becuase the number only appears twice this variable. 
#> x.n
#   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your function to include `na.omit(x)` like below -

```
M = data.frame( Name = c('name','name1','name','name1','name','name1'), Col1 = c(NA,1,3,4,5,NA) , Col2 = c(1,1,NA,5,8,4))

myData <- aggregate(M[,2],
                    by = list(VAR = M$Name), 
                    FUN = function(x) c(mean = mean(x,na.rm=T), sd = sd(x,na.rm=T),n=length(na.omit(x))))
myData <- do.call(data.frame, myData)

#     VAR x.mean     x.sd x.n
# 1  name    4.0 1.414214   2
# 2 name1    2.5 2.121320   2
```

Comment: Or just use `na.omit`. Something like `n=length((na.omit(x)))` will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse);
M %>%
    gather(k, v, -Name) %>%
    filter(complete.cases(.) & k == "Col1") %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(mean = mean(v), sd = sd(v), n = n())
## A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Name   mean    sd     n
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1 name   4.00  1.41     2
#2 name1  2.50  2.12     2
```

Explanation: We reshape from wide to long, remove rows with `NA` entries through `complete.cases`, and calculate the required summary statistics on the `Name`-grouped entries.